# Dynamically add HTML to CKEditor's Source (in particular, table information)

Tags: ckeditor

I'm trying to figure out how to get CKEditor to take the HTML that I want to feed it.  What I'd like to do is have a template for this table ready, then just click a button and it gets inserted into CKEditor.  I can't do this with the source code editor - the people using it won't have access to that and probably won't know how to do it anyhow.  But even so, there are still other problems at hand.

I've tried `getData` and `setData` on the instance, but when I do `setData` it ends up saving the table without any of the table tags.

This is what I did for that:

```
function PasteToFaxEnd() {
    var faxText = CKEDITOR.instances.faxMessageBodyText.getData();

    faxText += '<table style="width:600px;border:1px solid black;"><tr><td rowspan="4" style="width:50%;">Instructions</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Contact</td></tr><tr><td>Title</td></tr><tr><td>Email Address</td></tr></table>';

    CKEDITOR.instances.faxMessageBodyText.setData(faxText);
}
```

The result is just the text, no tags.

This worked slightly better, but it stripped my code of the very important border style.

```
function PasteToFaxEnd() {
    CKEDITOR.instances.faxMessageBodyText.insertHtml('<table style="width:600px;border:1px solid black;"><tr><td rowspan="4" style="width:50%;">Instructions</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr><tr><td>Contact</td></tr><tr><td>Title</td></tr><tr><td>Email Address</td></tr></table>');
}
```

The last thing I used was, instead of setting "style" on the table, I set a class instead, but I was not sure where I could put a class that the text inside the editor would read - it wasn't reading it from the page the editor was on.  With that said, this answer is not preferable: I need to send this text on to a PDF generator and I would rather have the styles set on the code so that I don't have to deal with that when I get to the PDF generator.  I would appreciate it if I saw such a thing though, at the very least having that knowledge could be useful.

Perhaps the answer lies in `insertHtml`, but I need that border to remain somehow. Any answer that keeps that styling would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Did you read about [Advanced Content Filter](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_advanced_content_filter) in CKEditor?